# Why are there so many images with alt text "a busy cat" on the network?

Tags: support, images, alt-text

While reviewing the results of [my script that repairs broken images](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/9d954d34385d2ac2597bbe864466259f) across the network, I noticed there are [many images](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22a+busy+cat%22) where the alt text is "a busy cat". It might be an older version of the automatically generated "enter image description here", but I don't remember it, and it appears in posts as recent as [2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807594). Given its prevalence and the variety of authors, it's likely to have been generated by something, but what?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is part of the inline help for the editor:

[image: screenshot of inline help]

Text version:

```
Images are exactly like links, but they have an exclamation point in front of them:

![a busy cat](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg)

![two muppets][1]

 [1]: https://i.imgur.com/I5DFV.jpg "tooltip"

The word in square brackets is the alt text, which gets displayed if the browser can't show the image. Be sure to include meaningful alt text for screen-reading software.
```

Comment: This doesn't completely answer the question. I take it you're implying that many users copy/paste the code into the body of their post?

Comment: @Joachim this help text is most probably the source. There may be different ways in which these alt texts actually end up in posts, but indeed copy-pasting from this help text directly into the post below seems to be a likely candidate.

Comment: @Joachim it's the obvious conclusion we can draw here. Text appears in the guide for how to format links, users copied it from there. We *know* users. Thus, this shouldn't really be unexpected.

Comment: @VLAZ Oh no, I completely agree. It just feels as if, while being logical and perhaps obvious, that conclusion could be drawn in the post :)

Comment: Great, that says something about how often I read those help pages :P

Comment: @Glorfindel it is easy to miss, especially since the official help https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images provides different examples.

Comment: Yeah, and it's easier to use the built-in uploader anyway. It's no surprise that many of those busy cat images are broken ...